# migrate.py: Cannot resolve 'django_db_logger.db_log_handler.DatabaseLogHandler'

Tags: python, django

so I am trying to migrate manage.py and I encounter this error:

> ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'db_log': Cannot resolve
>   'django_db_logger.db_log_handler.DatabaseLogHandler': No module named
>   django_db_logger

Here's the whole error log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\DUCNGU~1\Desktop\HAULER~1\api\venvi\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\DUCNGU~1\Desktop\HAULER~1\api\venvi\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\DUCNGU~1\Desktop\HAULER~1\api\venvi\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Users\DUCNGU~1\Desktop\HAULER~1\api\venvi\lib\site-packages\django\utils\log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\logging\config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\logging\config.py", line 576, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'db_log': Cannot resolve 'django_db_logger.db_log_handler.DatabaseLogHandler': No module named django_db_logger
```

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Does `C:\Users\DUCNGU~1\Desktop\HAULER~1\api\venvi\lib\site-packages\django\utils\log.py` exist?

Comment: @Jaberwocky yes it does. Should I post the whole log here?

Comment: Does `pip freeze` show `django-db-logger`?

Comment: @DucNguyen did you find a solution?